# UIImagePicker giving runtime error

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Here is my code. I have implemented `UIImagePicker` but at run time it does not show me the dialogue box for permission to access gallery in simulator

```
@IBOutlet var uploadImage: UIImageView!

@IBAction func upldImageBtn(sender: UIButton) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
    uploadImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    uploadImage.image = pickedImage
    uploadImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    uploadImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    uploadImage.layer.cornerRadius = uploadImage.frame.size.height/2
    uploadImage.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the simulator.

The option is available in the *Menu -> iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...*

If that does not help, please post details of the runtime error you are seeing.

Comment: I've tried the same but again getting the runtime error showing "This app does not have access to your photos or videos" .

Comment: Can you post the details of the error. Screen Shot of what you are seeing in the simulator and Logs will be helpful.

Comment: thank you for the help but now i am able to access library because this issue appear in iOS 9 when application Info.plist file contains a key: "CFBundleDisplayName" with empty string value. So it should not be empty.